# How do I resize these panels in my JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, border-layout

I'm creating a chess game where the main panel is using BorderLayout, there is a panel at `NORTH` for buttons, a panel at `CENTER` for the board itself (set to GridLayout) and a sidebar at `East`.

I have made the JFrame unresizable and I'd like the chessboard to fit the panels in so that the `East` panel is a lot wider (maybe 200 pixels) and the `board` remains a square. I can't figure out how to change the sizes of these components individually.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class GameWindow extends JFrame {

    private final JPanel playArea = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
    private final JButton[][] boardSquares = new JButton[8][8];
    private final JPanel board;
    private final JPanel sidebar = new JPanel();
    private final JLabel message = new JLabel("Game by ...");

    public  GameWindow() {
        playArea.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JToolBar tools = new JToolBar();


        tools.setFloatable(false);
        playArea.add(tools, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        tools.add(new JButton("New Game"));
        tools.add(new JButton("Save"));
        tools.add(new JButton("Restore")); 
        tools.addSeparator();
        tools.add(new JButton("Resign"))
        tools.addSeparator();
        tools.add(message);

        board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 8));
        board.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        playArea.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        playArea.add(sidebar, BorderLayout.EAST);

        Insets buttonMargin = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSquares.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < boardSquares[i].length; j++) {
                JButton square = new JButton();
                square.setMargin(buttonMargin);
                if ((i+j)%2 == 0) {
                    square.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                } 
                else {
                    square.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                board.setSize(600, 600);
                board.add(boardSquares[j][i] = square);
            }
        }
    }

    public final JComponent getChessBoard() {
    return board;
    }

    public final JComponent getGui() {
        return playArea;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GameWindow window = new GameWindow();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Checkers");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(window.getGui());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, since JDK 1.4, Java is encouraging the use of `BorderLayout` constants as `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`, `BorderLayout.LINE_START`, `BorderLayout.CENTER`, `BorderLayout.LINE_END` and `BorderLayout.PAGE_END` over the latter used by you.

Secondly you can simply override, the [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getPreferredSize--) of the said `JPanel`, in order for it to give, some size that you feel like will work for your use case. Use of `setPreferredSize()` is restricted, since, not all LayoutManagers use to respect the Dimension specified by it.

Hence you could do something like:

```
private final JPanel sidebar = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }
};
```

You can try this modified code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class GameWindow extends JFrame {

    private final JPanel playArea = new CustomPanel(710, 710);  
    private final JButton[][] boardSquares = new JButton[8][8];
    private final JPanel board;
    private final JPanel sidebar = new CustomPanel(100, 100);
    private final JLabel message = new JLabel("Game by ...");

    public  GameWindow() {
        playArea.setLayout(new BorderLayout(3,3));
        playArea.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JToolBar tools = new JToolBar();


        tools.setFloatable(false);
        playArea.add(tools, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        tools.add(new JButton("New Game"));
        tools.add(new JButton("Save"));
        tools.add(new JButton("Restore")); 
        tools.addSeparator();
        tools.add(new JButton("Resign"));
        tools.addSeparator();
        tools.add(message);

        board = new CustomPanel(600, 600);
        board.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 8));
        board.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        playArea.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        playArea.add(sidebar, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        Insets buttonMargin = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSquares.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < boardSquares[i].length; j++) {
                JButton square = new JButton();
                square.setOpaque(true);
                square.setMargin(buttonMargin);
                if ((i+j)%2 == 0) {
                    square.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                } 
                else {
                    square.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                board.add(boardSquares[j][i] = square);
            }
        }
    }

    private class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public CustomPanel(int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            setOpaque(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }
    }

    public final JComponent getChessBoard() {
    return board;
    }

    public final JComponent getGui() {
        return playArea;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GameWindow window = new GameWindow();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Checkers");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setContentPane(window.getGui());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Moreover, before setting the background of `JButton`, it would be wise to call `button.setOpaque(true)` property.

Comment: Why `frame.setSize(800, 800);` instead of `frame.pack();`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: My bad, I wanted to remove, all, I did saw that too, thought I removed that also :-) Thankyou for pointing out :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult to set the size of a `JPanel`. Just call `setPreferredSize()`. In your case to resize your East `JPanel`, call:

```
sidebar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
```

After that, your `LayoutManager` will set the size of your `JPanel` to 200,200.

To your other `JPanel`, `board`: It's impossible to make a `Component` (like a `JPanel`)  remaining a square. They always fit into rectangles. You would need to make your own subclass of `JComponent` and only paint everything in the square, and leave the rest transparent. Therefore, overwrite the method `JComponent.paintComponent(Graphics)`.

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Do think its better to overwrite `getPreferredSize` of the `JPanel` as _nIcE cOw_ suggested? I think its only more code with the same function

Comment: Same function, but better design.

Comment: @AndrewThompson What's better design on it? It's only more code

Comment: @msrd0: Actually, in some situations, `setXxXSize()` might won't be entertained by the `LayoutManager` concern. Though when asked, by the `LayoutManager`, `getPreferredSize()` is bound to give, the right `Dimension` to the calling entity.